# Proper way of connecting a molex connector to a breadboard

Tags: connector, breadboard

So I'm trying to [mount a keypad](http://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/0bf1ccbe6db1475979584c2b5804e50a.pdf) that requires a molex connector to a breadboard. The datasheet says it mates with Molex 2695 series or equivalent. So I thought I could just get away with a [10 position female mating connector](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0022013107/WM2008-ND/26447), which one end would go to the keypad and the other end would go to something like a male breakaway header. I was pretty surprised when I actually got the connector. One end looks like this, which fits nicely into my keypad

[image]

But the other end looks like this:

[image]

That hole is way too big for a typical breakaway male header pin.

What's the proper way of connecting something like this keypad to the breadboard?

Comment: solder 1/4W steel resistor leads to contacts and cut ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've only bought the housing. You have to buy the contacts, too. These are sold separately because there are multiple housing types with the same contacts. You also need the **matching** crimp tool.

Comment: Oh, can you provide any examples of contacts that would work with these housings? I haven't encountered something like this before

Comment: See http://www.molex.com/webdocs/datasheets/pdf/en-us/0022012021_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.pdf, right lower corner: *Use with*. BUT, as you need an expensive crimp tool for this, I would suggest to de-solder the connector from the keypad and just solder wires there. These connectors are for people who need 100+.

Comment: For small quantities, and when desperate, it is possible to crimp the contacts with pliers, then solder to ensure a good contact.  There are some inexpensive crimp tools, useful for small production work.

Comment: I would recommend to search for pre-assembled contacts + wires. Then just insert them into the housing. Crimping tools require proper wire/insulation sizing, and some skill. Keyword: "pre-crimped leads"

Comment: @Ali: I had liked to upvote that comment.

Answer (score 1):

That connector body is used with insertable contacts that would be crimped on the wires, then inserted in the larger holes in the connector.

The contacts are usually sold separately from the insulator.  On the DigiKey page for the connector body, the contacts are listed towards the bottom of the page under "Associated Product".